# RxSwift - Button Tap using Publish Subject

Tags: rx-swift

So I have a button inside my `ViewController` which is connected to `ViewModel` and than whenever the button is tapped, in my coordinator I navigate to another screen. The code is like this:

`VC`

```
btnShowShopsMap.rx.tap
            .bind(to: viewModel.selectShowMap)
```

`VM`

```
let selectShowMap: AnyObserver<Void>
    let showShopMap: Observable<Void>
//Inside init
 let _selectShowMap = PublishSubject<Void>()
        selectShowMap = _selectShowMap.asObserver()
        showShopMap = _selectShowMap.asObservable()
```

`Coordinator`

```
viewModel.showShopMap
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in self.showShopMap()})
            .disposed(by: userShopVC.disposeBag)
```

Is it possible to refactor above code? rather than using `PublishSubject` is there any other way to do what i am doing using `PublishSubject`

My VC, VM & Coordinator Flow

`Coordinator`

```
func showLoginScreen(logout: Bool = false) {

    guard let viewController = LoginViewController.instantiate(storyboard: .main) else { return }

    viewController.viewModelFactory = { inputs in
        let viewModel = LoginViewModel(inputs: inputs)
        viewModel.showHome
            .subscribe(onNext: {  isLogged in
                if isLogged {
                    self.showHomeScreen()
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: viewController.disposeBag)

        inputs.showOnboarding
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                self.showOnboardingScreen()
            })
            .disposed(by: viewController.disposeBag)
        return viewModel
    }
navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

`VC`

```
var viewModelFactory: (LoginViewModel.UIInputs) -> LoginViewModel = { _ in fatalError("factory not set")}

let inputs = LoginViewModel.UIInputs(userNumber: txtUserNumber.rx.text.orEmpty.asDriver(),
                                             password: txtPassword.rx.text.orEmpty.asDriver(),
                                             loginTapped: btnLogin.rx.tap.asSignal(),
                                             userNumberLostFocus: txtUserNumber.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd).asSignal(),
                                             passwordLostFocus: txtPassword.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd).asSignal(),
                                             indicator: indicator,
                                             showOnboarding: btnShowOnboarding.rx.tap.asObservable())
```

`VM`

```
struct  UIInputs {
    let userNumber: Driver<String>
    let password: Driver<String>
    let loginTapped: Signal<Void>
    let userNumberLostFocus: Signal<Void>
    let passwordLostFocus: Signal<Void>
    let indicator: ActivityIndicator
    let showOnboarding: Observable<Void>
}
 init(inputs: UIInputs) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very easy and simple way to solve my issue and avoid using `Subject`, As there was no logic related to my button in VM, I don't need pass my Button tap to my VM either by using `Observable` or using `Subject`. Instead I directly accessed my button in my Coordinator like this:

```
viewController.btnShowOnboarding.rx.tap
      .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
         self.showOnboardingScreen()
      })
     .disposed(by: viewController.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the view controller owns and instantiates the view model, you could pass the tap control event as an observable to the view model initializer, which then exposes it as an observable for the coordinator to subscribe to:

```swift
// VC:
let viewModel = ViewModel(..., showShopMap: btnShowShopMap.rx.tap.asObservable())

// VM:
let showShopMap: Observable<Void>

init(..., showShopMap: Observable<Void>) {
    self.showShopMap = showShopMap
}
```

I try not to use subjects whenever possible and instead just expose transformed observables that were passed in.

Comment: awesome thank, yeah that's why i was looking ways to remove Subjects, a question, I am using Inputs/Outputs Structs in my VM. So how should i access the my input in Coordinator?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between coordinator, view controller, and view model? Who instantiates whom?

Comment: let me update my questions to include that flow as well.

Comment: There's no need to access your input in your coordinator. Just add an additional line to your input struct for the `showShopMap` tap.

Comment: what you mean? i have already added by name of `showOnboarding`. and how would i access this in my coordinator?

Comment: Basically Coordintor initiates VC and VM.

Comment: Isn't `showOnboarding` a different input? For `showShopMap` just do it analogously to `showOnboarding`.

Comment: No, they are same, i know name are confusing. i am confused what you are saying, how should i avoid accessing inputs in coordinator.

Comment: Can you update your answer to add the coordinator flow as well.